# Issue with backup gem

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, backup

I just installed the gem backup. when I try something im getting this erroe. can I know what this is?

```
$ backup
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/backup-3.0.23/lib/backup/cli/utility.rb:240: warning:    parenthesize argument(s) for future version
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/backup-3.0.23/lib/backup/cli/utility.rb:104: wrong argument type Symbol (expected Proc) (TypeError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/backup-3.0.23/bin/backup:8
from /usr/bin/backup:19:in `load'
from /usr/bin/backup:19.


$ gem -v
1.4.0


gem list backup
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
backup (3.0.23)

ruby -v
ruby 1.8.6 (2007-09-24 patchlevel 111) [i686-linux]
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the line of code executed that generates this error?

Answer (score 0):

After browsing the backup gem docs, I've noticed the minimum version of ruby supported is 1.8.7.